# Why am I getting a second image of sprite that won't rotate and shouldn't be there?

Tags: python, image, animation, pygame, move

I am trying to create a TractorBeam (or Thrust) coming out of the back of my rocket ship and of course the sprite is to rotate with rocket ship. It seems to be working fine but I am getting a second image of the same TractorBeam image that stays in the same vertical position as the rocket ship rotates and the TractorBeam image rotates. I have it programmed the same as the laser coming out the front (except for different speed, lifetime, etc.) and the laser doesn't seem to have this unknown second image.

Any suggestions of where I am going wrong or how to eliminate this second unwanted image?

```
import pygame as pg
import os
from random import uniform
vec = pg.math.Vector2

TITLE = "GRAVITAR"
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60
GREY = (211, 211, 211)

# Player properties
ROCKET_SHIP = 'Images/Rocket_Ship.png'
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.00
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.1
PLAYER_ROT_SPEED = 200
LASER = 'Images/Laser_1.png'
LASER_SPEED = 400
LASER_LIFETIME = 1500
LASER_RATE = 150
LASER_COUNT = 1
LASER_SPREAD = 3
LASER_OFFSET = vec(20, -1)
TRACTOR_BEAM = 'Images/TractorBeam_1.png'
TRACTOR_BEAM_SPEED = 400
TRACTOR_BEAM_LIFETIME = 25
TRACTOR_BEAM_RATE = 25
TRACTOR_BEAM_COUNT = 1
TRACTOR_BEAM_SPREAD = 1
TRACTOR_BEAM_OFFSET = vec(-12, 0)

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.rocket_ship
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(x, y)
        self.rot = 90
        self.last_shot = 0
        self.thrust = False
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0

    def get_keys(self):
        self.rot_speed = 0
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.rot_speed = PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rot_speed = -PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_UP]:
            self.vel += vec(PLAYER_ACC, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            self.shoot()
        if keys[pg.K_t]:
            self.tractor_beam()
        self.vel += self.acc + self.vel * PLAYER_FRICTION
        max_vel = 1.75
        self.vel[0] = max(-max_vel, min(max_vel, self.vel[0]))
        self.vel[1] = max(-max_vel, min(max_vel, self.vel[1]))
        self.pos += self.vel

    def shoot(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_shot > LASER_RATE:
            self.last_shot = now
            dir = vec(1, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
            pos = self.pos + LASER_OFFSET.rotate(-self.rot)
            for i in range(LASER_COUNT):
                spread = uniform(-LASER_SPREAD, LASER_SPREAD)
                Laser(self.game, pos, dir.rotate(spread), self)

    def tractor_beam(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_shot > TRACTOR_BEAM_RATE:
            self.last_shot = now
            dir = vec(1, 0).rotate(-self.rot + 180)
            pos = self.pos + TRACTOR_BEAM_OFFSET.rotate(-self.rot)
            spread = uniform(-TRACTOR_BEAM_SPREAD, TRACTOR_BEAM_SPREAD)
            TractorBeam(self.game, pos, dir.rotate(spread), self)

    def update(self):
        self.get_keys()
        self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed * self.game.dt) % 360
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.game.rocket_ship, self.rot)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = 0
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = WIDTH
        if self.pos.y > HEIGHT:
            self.pos.y = 0
        if self.pos.y < 0:
            self.pos.y = HEIGHT


class Laser(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, pos, dir, player):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites  # , game.bullet
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.player = player
        self.image = game.laser
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = vec(pos)
        self.rect.center = pos
        self.vec = dir * LASER_SPEED * uniform(0.9, 1.1)
        self.spawn_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.rot = 90

    def update(self):
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.game.laser, self.player.rot - 90)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos += self.vec * self.game.dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if pg.time.get_ticks() - self.spawn_time > LASER_LIFETIME:
            self.kill()


class TractorBeam(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, pos, dir, player):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.player = player
        self.image = game.tractor_beam
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = vec(pos)
        self.rect.center = pos
        self.pos = vec(pos)
        self.vec = dir * TRACTOR_BEAM_SPEED * uniform(0.9, 1.1)
        self.spawn_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.rot = 0

    def update(self):
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.game.tractor_beam, self.player.rot - 90)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos += self.vec * self.game.dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if pg.time.get_ticks() - self.spawn_time > TRACTOR_BEAM_LIFETIME:
           self.kill()

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize pygame and create window
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        pg.key.set_repeat(10, 50)
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '568, 101'
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        self.rocket_ship = pg.image.load(ROCKET_SHIP).convert_alpha()
        self.rocket_ship = pg.transform.scale(self.rocket_ship, (36, 18))
        self.laser = pg.image.load(LASER).convert_alpha()
        self.laser = pg.transform.scale(self.laser, (3, 8))
        self.tractor_beam = pg.image.load(TRACTOR_BEAM).convert_alpha()
        self.tractor_beam = pg.transform.scale(self.tractor_beam, (30, 30))

    def new(self):
        # Start a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.lasers = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.tractorBeams = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        # Game loop
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def update(self):
        # Game loop update
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def events(self):
        # Game loop events
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False

    def draw(self):
        # Game loop draw
        pg.display.set_caption("{:.2f}".format(self.clock.get_fps()))
        self.screen.fill(GREY)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)

        # After drawing everything, flip display
        pg.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass

g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be 2 tractor beams, but there is just 1. However, the `update` method of the `TractorBeam` instance is not called in the first frame in which it is drawn. It is constructed in the `update` loop of the the *Group* from the `player`. *Sprites* that are add to the *Group* during `update` are not updated in this frame, but in the next frame.
You have to invoke `update` manually once:

```py
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

       def tractor_beam(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_shot > TRACTOR_BEAM_RATE:
            self.last_shot = now
            dir = vec(1, 0).rotate(-self.rot + 180)
            pos = self.pos + TRACTOR_BEAM_OFFSET.rotate(-self.rot)
            spread = uniform(-TRACTOR_BEAM_SPREAD, TRACTOR_BEAM_SPREAD)
            
            beam = TractorBeam(self.game, pos, dir.rotate(spread), self)
            beam.update()
```

There is the same problem with the laser, but it is barely noticeable.

Comment: "It's always a good day to learn something new"... thanks Rabbid76, makes perfect sense.